# How to find out highlighted element(s) on web page by using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

Development Environment: Java, Selenium WebDriver, JUnit

I have to automate a test case where i have to enter values in couple of field leaving other fields blank. As i enter submit button, error message will be thrown and all the blanks fields will be highlighted.

Example url: https://www.salesforce.com/in/form/trial/freetrial.jsp?d=70130000000Enyk

I do not know how to find out highlighted fields using webdriver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for input-fields inside a `div` with class `error`.

```
driver.get("https://www.salesforce.com/in/form/trial/freetrial.jsp?d=70130000000Enyk");
driver.findElement(By.className("submit")).click();
List<WebElement> errors = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.error input"));
```

Comment: The provided code has helped to identify the highlighted fields. But i did not get the logic behind using "div.error input" in By.cssSelector() method? Can you please suggest?

Comment: You did not get why you need to search for ```div.error input``` or you don’t understand what this does?

Comment: I don't understand what this does. Would appreciate if you could explain?

Comment: It searches for every input element descendant of a div with class error. Quite the same if you would select every div, iterate over them and check if the class-attribute is containing 'error' and if true search if one of the child-elements is a input-element. Take a look at the [w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)